# Getting $f(x) =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n(n-1)}$, $|x|<1$.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In its convergence range, we have that the function $f(x)$ has a Taylor series shown [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIqW9.jpg).

What is $f(x)$ itself?

Here is the Taylor series at $x=0$ for the function:

$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n(n-1)}
$$

I'm not sure about the $1$ in $n-1$.

Comment: Use partial fractions to simplify the sum.

Comment: Linked images of problems are frowned upon here, IIRC. Check out the FAQ: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/18532/42969 – Both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7Bx%5En%7D%7Bn(n-1)%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: yes , thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}=-\ln\left(1-x \right),\quad |x|<1.
$$ Then writing
$$
\frac{x^n}{n(n-1)}=x\frac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}-\frac{x^n}{n},\quad n\ge2,
$$ may help.